# jQuery selector returns prevObject instead of normal element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have some problems with selecting elements, with Jquery.
When i try to select a element:

```
var images = $("#htmlChunk").find("img.Thumb");
console.log(images);
```

i get this result:

```
>[<img>, <img>, prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: #document, selector: "#htmlChunk img.Thumb"]
```

What is causing this returned result?
I tried some things but still dont get the result i wanted.

i tried to wrap the code to avoid conflict's.
i tried to clear the object

This was something i found on the web.
http://drupal.org/node/272557

```
var images = $("#htmlChunk")['prevObject'].find("img.Thumb");
```

i get returned a object now,
but thats also not what i wanted.

I jumped into this project so i am not well-known with the script.
i tried to search for prevObject in the js files but could'nt find any.

I think the problem is that it is interfering with some other javascript file.
any ideas? directions?

Edit:
htmlChunk:

```
<div id="htmlChunk">
    <div class="ngg-albumoverview">
        <div class="ngg-album-compact">
            <div class="ngg-album-compactbox">
                <div class="ngg-album-link">
                    <a class="Link" href="http://........">
                        <img class="Thumb" alt="Personeelsevent" src="http://.........">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h4><a class="ngg-album-desc" title="Personeelsevent" href="http://.....">Personeelsevent</a></h4>
            <p><a href="http:///.......">bekijk dit album</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The result you're seeing is the properties of the returned jQuery object. Without a sample of your HTML, it's impossible to help you further.

Comment: Just use '.get()' after 'find', and you will have array from objects. Example $(parent).find('iframe[src*="vimeo.com"]').get();

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your `images` variable is a jQuery object, so what you're seeing output in your browser's console seems to be that object. The specific output suggests that the call to `.find()` isn't actually matching any elements; compare the two console outputs from [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhDp4/1/) (in Chrome).

When you call a jQuery function - such as `.find()`, `.filter()`, etc - that narrows down, or changes, the list of matched elements on an existing jQuery object the resulting jQuery object also contains a reference to the state before that function was run, which is what you're seeing as `prevObject`. This is what it uses to revert back to when you call the [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) function.

Let's break down your code:

```
var images = $(".htmlChunk").find("img.Thumb");
```

The first part - `$(".htmlChunk")` - matches all elements that have the class `htmlChunk` on them, and returns a jQuery object containing those elements.

Then you call `.find("img.Thumb")` which looks for all elements that are descendents of the already matched elements (those with the class `htmlChunk`) that satisfy the criteria of being an `<img>` element and having the class `Thumb` on them.

You could use a single selector to retrieve the elements, which might give you better results:

```
var images = $(".htmlChunk img.Thumb");
```

If you want an array of the actual DOM elements, rather than a jQuery object containing them, you can use the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function:

```
var elementArray = images.get();
```

---

To address the edit to the question to include the HTML:

You're using `$(".htmlChunk")` to obtain the initial element. However, that `<div>` element has an **ID**, not a class, of `htmlChunk` so that code won't select the element you need. You'll want to use the following:

```
var images = $("#htmlChunk").find("img.Thumb");
```

Note the `#` rather than the `.` in the selector.

Comment: I got the result indeed now, because of the ID(stupid mistake my bad) but i still dont know where that prevObject comes from and why? normally you get the DOM elements in a array, never seen this before that it returns a weird object. just for clarify things up how do you get rid of this object for example

Comment: or maby it looks different because chrome update there browser lately and the console shows more info now then it did before so thats maby why i am confused

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your trying to select class ".htmlChunk", but does not exist. Try selecting by id instead.

```
var images = $("#htmlChunk").find("img.Thumb");
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
   function getId() {
             var ids = $(".htmlChunk").find("img.thumb"); //it wiill return array of image
             var sid = $(".htmlChunk").find("img#img2"); //it wiill return wat image you want
             $(".htmlChunk span").text("arrays:" + ids[0] + "  :  " + ids[1] +
             "simple imge:" + sid);
         }


    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick= "getId();"/>


  <div class="htmlChunk">
        <img alt="" src="img/Desert.jpg" class="thumb" id="img1" />
       <img alt="" src="img/Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="thumb" id="img2" />
        <span></span>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

isn't prevObject just a property of the result?

you could understand it as "the result has the following prevObject ->"