# jQuery returns prevObject....sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove an item from the DOM using jQuery and sometimes get a prevObject rather than an element. I understand that prevObject is returned when no element is found, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13307109/3194491)

I have created a single page app which adds elements to a playlist in two distinct ways, one via drag and drop and the other through a button press. Both ways call the same function, passing in the relevant information.

When I click the remove button of an element that has been dragged and dropped it is successfully removed, but any items added to the playlist via the button will not remove because of prevObject being returned by jQuery.

The project [can be found here](http://purelywebdesign.co.uk/sandbox/videointerface/) if you need to have a proper look.

**HTML (from chrome dev tools)**

Top item has been dragged and dropped, second via the button.

```
<aside class="col-sm-12 ui-sortable" id="sortable">
    <article class="dropped" id="2">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/gnbLLQwZxeA/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Put social back in social media">
        <h3>Put social back in social media</h3>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <a href="#" title="Remove item" id="remove2"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
    </article>
    <article class="dropped" id="3">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ccFLVPNBRE4/mqdefault.jpg" alt="jQuery Performance Myths and Realities">
        <h3>jQuery Performance Myths and Realities</h3>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <a href="#" title="Remove item" id="remove3"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a></article>
    // more items here
</aside>
```

**function that adds items to playlist**

```
var addToPlayList = function(title, image, id){
    var playlistItem = '';
    playlistItem += '<article class="dropped" id="' + id + '">';
    playlistItem += '<img src="' + image + '" alt="' + title + '">';
    playlistItem += '<h3>' + title + '</h3>';
    playlistItem += '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
    playlistItem += '<a href="#" title="Remove item" id="remove' + id +'"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>';
    playlistItem += '</article>';

    $(playlistItem).insertBefore('.droppable');

    $('.playlist #remove' + id).click(function(ev) {
        removePlaylistItem(id);
    });
    fixClearfix();
}
```

**function to remove items from the playlist**

```
var removePlaylistItem = function(id){
    var itemToRemove = $('aside article#' + id);
    console.log(itemToRemove); // returns prev object for items added by button
    itemToRemove.remove();

    var video = findVideoByID(id);
    displayVideo(video, id);
    fixClearfix();
}
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fully specify your jQuery selector, (i.e. change `'aside article#' + id` to be `'aside article[id=' + id + ']'` it should work.

Another issue I noticed is that when videos are dragged, they are removed from the main list. When they are added through the button, they are not.

Comment: You are amazing :) Thanks for the answer, and the bug report.

Comment: No problem. If I find out why this is happening, i'll comment back. I always assumed `$('#a')` and `$('[id=a]')` were equivalent.

Comment: Oh, figured it out. Its related to the other bug. When you add it through the button, the video isn't removed from the main list, where it also has an id equal to the index. Then, when you try to select with the shortcut syntax in the remove method, it returns nothing because it encounters two elements on the page with the same id. The longhand version of the selector is more forgiving (but it might also be selecting the wrong element).

Comment: The real fix is to ensure that IDs don't get duplicated - it's not legal HTML otherwise.

Comment: @user1403582 Thanks for taking the time to look into it further. With the video removed from the grid when its added to playlist via the button the original selector works just fine. Ironically I left the duplicate video bug until I had figured out the selection issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using numeric IDs, and (illegal) duplicate IDs, consider storing the ID as a `data` attribute on the `<article>` elements:

```
<article data-id="1" ...>
```

Then, on the remove button there's actually no need for an ID at all, and better yet you can use a delegated event handler that'll work on all entries regardless of when they're added:

```
$('.playlist').on('click', '.remove', function(ev) {
    var id = $(this).closest('article').data('id');
    removePlaylistItem(id);
});
```

thus avoiding having to dynamically register a separate event handler for each and every article in the list.  Note that the `remove` link now just has a class (since every such link is treated identically)` and it figures out the ID by looking at its ancestor.

Your `removePlaylistItem` function would need a *little* work to function with the above, but in the `click` handler you already know which element it is you want to remove, so you shouldn't *really* have to go traverse the DOM to find it again.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. With the bug fix in the other answer theres never two elements with the same id on page as I've used the data and name attributes elsewhere. I will be using delegated event handlers as you suggest though to prevent repeated calls to the DOM. Many thanks.